# Хочу Pyqt5.8 установить, но тут загвоздка

Tags: qt, python-3.x, pyqt5

Пишу в консоль команду:

```
pip3 install PyQt5
```

и у меня вылезает красный текст:

> Exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/zhenyamega/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main status = self.run(options, args)
>
> File "/home/zhenyamega/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run prefix=options.prefix_path,
>
> File "/home/zhenyamega/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install **kwargs
>
> File "/home/zhenyamega/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
>       self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
>
> File "/home/zhenyamega/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
>       isolated=self.isolated,
>
> File "/home/zhenyamega/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
>       clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
>
> File "/home/zhenyamega/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
>       ensure_dir(destdir)
>
> File "/home/zhenyamega/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/utils/**init**.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
>       os.makedirs(path)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
>       mkdir(name, mode)
>
> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Отказано в доступе: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5-5.8.dist-info'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Отказано в доступе: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5-5.8.dist-info'
```

Внимательно читайте код ошибки, у вас нет прав на установку в эту директорию. Если вы на Линуксе, попробуйте `sudo pip3 install PyQt5`

Comment: Хорошо попробую

Comment: @ЕвгенийКаратаев: не стоит на Linux `sudo pip` делать. Или что-то вроде `apt install python3-pyqt5` используйте или в virtualenv выполните `pip install PyQt5` это просто копирует бинарный wheel и работает (предполагая, что `libqt5*` пакеты уже стоят).

Comment: @jfs, Не стоит человека во всякие дебри затягивать. Если человек первый раз сталкивается с пайтоном, я думаю проще сделать pip install, чем вникать в какие-то не понятные для него, еще виртуальные окружения. С таким подходом новичку вообще ничего нельзя делать, так как он все, по сути, делает не правильно.

Comment: @Klym: `sudo pip` может испортить системные приложения написанные на Питоне. Не нужно вредные советы, которые могут систему сломать давать.

Comment: @jfs, Это каким образом он может их испортить?

Comment: Почитайте, [почему вообще virtualenv на свет появились](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)

Comment: @jfs у нас где-нибудь есть подробный ответ про virtualenv?

Comment: @NickVolynkin есть объяснение [зачем virtualenv нужны, какую проблему это решает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/651952/23044)

Comment: @jfs тогда почему бы не задубликатить? В том вопросе есть ответ на этот.

Comment: @NickVolynkin как установить библиотеку в рассматриваемом случае и почему не стоит использовать один из методов установки это несколько разные вопросы.