# Почему не стоит использовать sudo pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip

Почему не нужно использовать `sudo pip`? Я не до конца понимаю этот аспект. Мне предложили задать отдельный вопрос. Многим другим людям это тоже может быть полезно знать.

Comment: @Nofate зря метку ubuntu убрали: ответ не на Ubuntu может быть другим (к примеру, на macOS, если `sudo pip` вызывает pip из brew, а не системный, то и проблемы, что неотносящиеся системные утилиты сломаются, может не быть).

Comment: @jfs `sudo pip` в дебиане, редхате, генту и арче принципиально иначе работает?

Comment: @Nofate: я знаю ответ на Ubuntu. python команда и непользовательские утилиты, использующие python, могут на других системах паковаться по-другому.

Comment: @jfs ну как минимум ubuntu и debian тут будут вести себя идентично.

Comment: @Nofate: pip на Ubuntu может содержать патчи, которых нет в debian Так что "идентично" нельзя утверждать, хотя ответ это не должно менять: *не трогайте файлы, установленные системным менеджером пакетов* (если они на это специально не рассчитаны -- как, к примеру, конфиги).

Comment: Принятый ответ совершенно не соответствует тому что я имел в виду в обсуждении, которое вы по ссылке привели: *«не стоит на Ubuntu выполнять `sudo pip* install` вообще. Так можно сломать системные утилиты, использующие Питон. В системные области, следует ставить используя системный же менеджер пакетов. К примеру, `sudo apt-get install python3-selenium`»*. Если [мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/651952/23044) не ясен в текущей форме: спрашивайте, я могу подробнее отдельные моменты объяснить.

Comment: [pep-668](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0668/) подробно обсуждает эту тему

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Почему НЕ стоит использовать `sudo pip install`?

При установке пакета вы не просто размещаете его в своей файловой системе, но и выполняете скрипт `setup.py`. Поскольку в PyPI загрузить пакет может кто угодно, вы не можете быть уверены, что `setup.py` не содержит код, выполнение которого под пользователем root нежелательно/опасно/недопустимо.

По уровню опасности это равносильно выполнению под суперпользователем shell-скрипта "из облака":

```
wget -O - http://example.com/some/unsafe/script.sh | bash
```

## Как же быть?

### Вариант 1

Кроме случаев, когда вам крайне необходимо установить пакет из-под `root`-а, вы можете использовать

```
pip install --user mypackage
```

чтобы установить пакет в репозиторий текущего пользователя `$HOME/.local/lib/pythonx.y/site-packages/`.

### Вариант 2

Использовать изолированные окружения, например `virtualenv`. В этом случае у вас под рукой будет неограниченное количество рабочих окружений (например, под каждый проект, с разными версиями python), которые не будут мешать друг другу.

Пакеты будут храниться в `$HOME/.virtualenvs/$ENVNAME/lib/pythonx.y/site-packages/` вместе с нужной версией python и сторонними бинарниками, а переключение окружений выполняется командой `workon $ENVNAME`.

IDE, вроде PyCharm, знают про виртуальные окружения и умеют с ними работать.

Comment: Использование виртуального окружение вообще является хорошим тоном по многим причинам, в первую очередь изолированность - меньше рисков кинфликтов пакетов при обновлении версий, установки сторонних библиотек и т.п. Кроме того будет легче переносить зависимости и для тестов и в продекшн, например `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Comment: Это red herring. Устанавливая чужое ПО, вы уже проявляете доверие авторам. Можно беспокоиться о деталях типа https и проверке gpg подписей для дистрибутива (иногда). Но реальная проблема это неочевидная поломка из-за sudo pip казалось бы никак не связанных системных пакетов, устпновленных сейчас *или в будущем*.

Answer (score 17):

Основная причина та же почему virtualenv существует: если у вас есть Питон-пакеты `foo`, `bar`, которые требуют разные версии `libbaz` библиотеки, то `sudo pip install bar` может обновить версию `libbaz`, сломав `foo` пакет, ожидающий более старую версию из системных пакетов.

Гипотетический cценарий, но с реальными пакетами: допустим у вас стоял `python-matplotlib` Ubuntu пакет и вы обновили его до PyPI версии, используя `sudo pip`. На первый взгляд всё замечательно, вы успешно построили желаемый график. Через пару дней вы обнаружили, что поиск книг в `calibre` стал неустойчиво работать (не можете найти книгу по запросу, который раньше её находил). Потратив какое-то время на отладку проблемы, если вам повезёт, то вы сможете локализовать её к проблеме с версией `pyparsing` модуля, используемого как в `calibre` так и в `matplotlib`.

То есть проблема с `sudo pip install matplotlib -U` не в том, что код с PyPI выполняется от имени root (c точки зрения безопасности, проблемы хуже, чем с `sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib`, но не особо для типичного разработчика -- можно даже gpg-подпись проверить для скаченного matplotlib wheel, если есть желание).

Проблема в том, что `sudo pip` к трудно диагностируемым проблемам может вести из-за несоответствия ожидания пакетов, упакованных для apt-get и версий пакетов с PyPI.

Именно поэтому, пакеты, которые должны быть особенно независимы, такие как `pip`, `pkg_resources` используют свою локальную копию:  `<package>._vendor.pyparsing`.

Иногда можно использовать радикальных подход и ставить каждую утилиту в своё virtualenv, к примеру, используя [`pipx` команду](https://pipxproject.github.io/pipx/):

```
$ pipx install youtube-dl
```

Это позволяет обновлять `youtube-dl`, не трогая пакеты, которые могут использоваться другим ПО на системе. И обратное, обновление других пакетов не сломает youtube-dl команду.

Недостаток подобного подхода в том, что при исправлении дырки в безопасности в какой-нибудь зависимости, её придётся обновлять в каждом virtualenv отдельно.

По сути, используя `sudo pip`, вы берёте на себя ответственность о том, что все установленные вами версии пакетов и их зависимости будут совместимы с пакетами, установленными системным менеджером пакетов сейчас и *в будущем*. Обычно это работа создателей Linux дистрибутивов, типа Ubuntu -- они стараются, чтобы версии пакетов, распространяемые в дистрибутиве, работали бы друг с другом.

Устанавливая `pip install --user <package>`, вы не сломаете программы, которые от другого пользователя запускаются. Ставя в virtualenv,  вы изолируете систему от возможных изменений и наоборот (если `--system-site-packages` опция не указана при создании) изолируете пакеты внутри virtualenv от изменений в системе.

Для удобства управления virtualenv, [можно `virtualenvwrapper` поставить](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Чем вызван минус?

Comment: мисскликом, извиняюсь

Comment: @fellzo не страшно, бывает.

Answer (score 6):

Это актуально не только для pip, использование прав суперпользователя может быть черевато выполнением произвольного кода, который может навредить системе.

Если не получается установить какой-то пакет без root'а, то, вероятно просто неверно выставленно разрешение на директорию с пакетами python

Comment: Как тогда юзать pip? Он всегда хочет прав суперпользователя?

Comment: Установка любого ПО — это по определению выполнение прозвольного года, и тут уже неважно, суперпользователь или нет :)

Comment: Действительно, но при использовании sudo есть возмжность выполнить самый банальный rm -rf / . И будет неиллюзорно весело.

Comment: И нет, он не всегда хочет прав суперпользователя

Comment: rm -rf и без sudo натворит бед, потому что все сверхважные данные всё равно обычно лежат в домашней папке, для которой sudo не нужен)

Comment: но при этом с ~90% вероятностью их можно быстро восстановить, а вот если умрет ядро будет печально

Comment: Если умрёт ядро, восстановить будет даже проще, потому что придётся грузить какой-нибудь LiveCD, в котором можно будет примонтировать винт только для чтения, что поспособствует спасению файлов)) Но ладно, предлагаю закончить оффтоп)

Comment: @fellzo  В итоге, на мой вопрос, так и не было дано однозначного ответа: кто-то считает так, кто-то -- сяк.

Comment: думаю злоумышленник не будет делать rm -rf. А установить в систему ботнет, или начать прослушивать сетевой интерфейс...

Comment: я привел rm -rf лишь как пример

Comment: При делегировании к учетной записи привилегированного (не только `sudo`) пользователя идет установка в корневые директории системы к которым по умолчанию на многих Unix подобных системах ограниченный доступ на запись. Если у разработчика НЕТ доступа или знаний о системе на которой идет разработка - стоит немного подтянутся и не стрелять себе в ногу. Есть специализированные дистрибутивы, где НЕ нужны права привилегированного пользователя - NixOS и GUIX. Любая среда разработки создается на лету (Python, Go, Haskell, Rust, Perl, C, R...)

Answer (score 1):

Правильный ответ почему-то не написан - `sudo pip` возникает соблазн использовать, когда необходимо установить пакет python в общесистемную установку python. При этом все вышенаписанное в ответах верно - это и попросту опасно, и можно перепутать версии python, которые установлены в системе (зачастую могут быть и python2, и python3 и другие версии сосуществовать на одном узле). Как быть? Если все-таки pip'а никак не избежать - то для начала четко указывать какую версию python мы используем:

`python3 -m pip install ...`

или

`python -m pip install ...`

Вторая важная вещь - если необходимо установить что-либо в системный питон - вместо `pip install` СТРОГО рекомендуется использовать встроенный пакетный менеджер операционной системы. Почему? Потому что `pip install` НИЧЕГО в системном пакетном менеджере не прописывает и при следующем обновлении системы получите мешанину из пакетов или они будут попросту переписаны.

Например, вместо `pip install docker` на debian-based вводим `apt install python-docker` (или `apt install python3-docker`, если нам нужно установить пакет в окружение третьего питона).

Во всех остальных случаях - лучше рассмотреть возможность установки пакета через `pip --user install` в локальное окружение пользователя или virtual env.

Дополнительно еще могу добавить, что при использовании `pip install -r requirements.txt` РЕГУЛЯРНО возникает проблема, что в зависимости от порядка установки пакетов pip может притащить разные версии зависимых пакетов (например, A зависит от B версии 10, но не новее 11, C зависит от B новее 11 - в результате имеем A, C и B версии новее 11). Вроде как ведутся работы в направлении того, чтобы pip научился правильно резолвить зависимости (по графу), но они точно еще не закончены.