# Добавление изображения в файл .docx с помощью python

Tags: python, файлы, изображения

Обычными средствами не получается добавить изображение в конец файла.
Код

```
old_image = open('Pupils.png', 'r').read()
new_image = open('new_pro.docx', 'a')
new_image.write(old_image)
new_image.close()
```

Какие есть способы решить эту задачу?

Comment: Во-первых, чтобы считать и записать изображение нужно использовать байты: `rb`, `wb`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python хорош тем что на каждый случай есть библиотека. В данном случае это либа docx. Сначала установим её (на Linux нужны права root)

```
pip install python-docx
```

А затем просто добавим изображение.

```
from docx import Document

document = Document("./foo.docx")

document.add_picture('./image-filename.png')
document.save("./foo.docx")
```

Comment: По поводу прав суперпользователя при установке библиотеки: [Почему не стоит юзать sudo pip?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/651860/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-sudo-pip)

Answer (score 3):

К библиотеке python-docx предлагаю добавить docxtpl. Работает очень просто. Нужно сделать шаблон и в нем разметить место куда чего вставлять. На гите можно посмотреть примеры разметки. [Примеры](https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template/tree/master/tests/test_files)

Answer (score 2):

*.docx - это Zip-архив со служебными файлами, описывающими документ. Служебные файлы в формате [XML](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML), поэтому вы не можете добавить в документ изображение приведенным способом (просто дописав байты в архив). Для решения вам необходимо использовать специальные библиотеки, которые берут парсинг XML на себя и гарантируют корректность получившегося документа согласно [стандарту](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML). Пример такой библиотеки: [`python-docx`](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/lates) (`pip install python-docx`). Пример из [официальной документации](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#adding-a-picture):

```
from docx import Document

doc = Document("<PATH_TO_DOCX>")
doc.add_picture('image-filename.png')
```

Вместо полного пути к изображению вы можете использовать [file-like](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) объект (например, `BytesIO`):

```
with open("yo.png", "rb") as img:
    doc.add_picture(img)
```

При необходимости вы можете [изменять размер изображения](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#image-size). В этом деле главное помнить, что в документе все размеры - это сантиметры, дюймы и производные, а не пиксели.