# Как установить gspread на mac os x?

Tags: python, pip

Как установить GSPREAD? При установке пишу `pip3 install gspread`, или просто `pip`, и вот результат:

> Installing collected packages: requests, gspread
>   Exception:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
>   status = self.run(options, args)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
>   prefix=options.prefix_path,
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
>   **kwargs
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
>   self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
>   isolated=self.isolated,
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
>   clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
>   ensure_dir(destdir)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/utils/**init**.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
>   os.makedirs(path)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs
>   mkdir(name, mode)
>   PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37553953/permission-error-pip-install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запускать pip надо от рута. "PermissionError" это ошибка доступа, так как обычный юзер не имеет права устанавливать пакет для всех

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: @DanTheMan Если у вас линукс то: `sudo pip...`

Comment: По поводу прав суперпользователя при установке библиотеки: [Почему не стоит юзать sudo pip?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/651860/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-sudo-pip)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте Conda:

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge gspread
```