# установка bigartm на Linux Mint

Tags: python, linux, linux-mint

Добрый вечер,

Не смог установить bigartm на linux mint.
ранее загрузил anaconda и cледовал инструкции: http://docs.bigartm.org/en/stable/installation/index.html

но на последнем шаге "sudo make install" вышла след. ошибка
несмотря на то, что setuptools установлен
[image: скриншот]:

Comment: есть подозрение, что версия библиотеки и требуемая версия не совпадают (то есть, одно от второго питона, другое от третьего)

Comment: anaconda и инструкции в вопросе, которая для системного питона пакет ставит, никак не связаны -- следует или одно использовать или другое (проверьте упакован ли BigARTM для conda). Также: [Почему не стоит юзать sudo pip?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/651952/23044)

Comment: чтобы просто попробовать: [`docker run --rm -ti ofrei/bigartm ipython3` (несколько GB изображение)](http://docs.bigartm.org/en/stable/installation/docker.html).