# Для чего нужен virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv

Для чего нужен `virtualenv` ? О какой изоляции речь ? Почему когда делают проекты на `Flask` или `Django`, то обязательно используют `virtualenv` ?

[Тут](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) пишут, что он нужен если нужно установить определённую версию библиотеки без обновления (или устаревания) существующей библиотеки. Только для этого ?

Comment: virtualenv нужен для создания предсказуемого, 100% (по крайней мере, максимально) повторяемого окружения. Т.е. в процессе разработки и на "боевом" сервере должны быть одни и те же версии библиотек, например. Нужно это потому, что библиотеки имеют свойство обновляться, и иногда ломать совместимость с предыдущими версиями, или могут новые баги появиться и т.д. Если у вас на боевом сервере и на компьютере где ведется разработка разные версии библиотек, то внезапно может оказаться, что на вашем компьютере приложение будет работать, а на боевом сервере нет.

Comment: Кроме того, это позволяет на одном сервере по-очереди или одновременно использовать, например, django-1.8 для старых проектов и 2.0 для свежих. Каждую со своим набором сопутствующих пакетов.

Comment: [Почему не стоит юзать sudo pip?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/651952/23044)

Comment: Лично я считаю «создание предсказуемого, повторяемого окружения» плохой идеей и использую virtualenv только для изоляции разных версий библиотек (как с упомянутой выше django), а на боевых серверах вообще не использую

Comment: @andreymal, не каждый может позволить себе такую роскошь - иметь выделенный сервер для единственного приложения на Python... И как вы тестируете новые версии модулей и откатываетесь на старые в случае проблем (иногда проблемы "вылезают" только на "production" ...)?

Comment: @MaxU для тестирования достаточно обычного домашнего ноутбука с virtualenv'ами и в крайнем случае парой виртуалок в виртуалбоксе, не понял при чём тут роскошь

Comment: @MaxU есть docker, VMware, итд.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Виртуальное окружение необходимо для того, чтобы решить проблему несовместимости библиотек внутри проекта. Предположим, что вы работаете над каким-нибудь проектом, который использует определенную библиотеку. Затем у вас появляется новый проект в котором вы решили использовать эту же библиотеку, но новой версии, которая по каким-то причинам не совместима со старой. И тут вы можете создать виртуальное окружение для нового проекта, установить в него необходимую версию библиотеки и иметь возможность работать над двумя проектами сразу.